# I want a drop down form with a submit button in php

Tags: php

I've edited the code. Is it right now?

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <select name="event">
      <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select a Make</option>
      <option value="1">Honda</option>
      <option value="2">Volkswagen</option>
  </select>

  <select name="event2">
     <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select a Model</option>
     <option value="1">Civic</option>
     <option value="2">Passat</option>
  </select>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: u have all just add the submit button and close the form.

Comment: You are _very clear_ on what you need. Expect answers soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form action="" method="POST" name ="testfrm" id="testfrm">
<select name="event">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select a Make</option>
    <option value="1">Honda</option>
    <option value="2">Volkswagen</option>
</select>

<select name="event2">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select a Model</option>
    <option value="1">Civic</option>
    <option value="2">Passat</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" name="btnsbmt" id="btnsbmt" />
</form>
```

--
Thanks

Comment: Hey help me with this. I ve 2 drop down lists, when i select Honda in 1st list then it shd show al Honda cars in 2nd list. Same 4 al models

Comment: Do you have javascript in that page ?

Comment: It should be of external resource error. Try to run this on: http://htmledit.squarefree.com/

Comment: i got d drop down lists. but i wan it to work as hw m telling u. wen i select honda in 1st list it shd show oly honda's cars on 2nd list.

Comment: I am trying to create two dropdown menus in one of my forms so that they behave in the following way:

the first menu consists of "categories" of items, which I hard coded into the form. i am looking to relate the second menu with the first one such that, as soon as you choose an option from the first menu, the second menu lists only the name of those items that falls in the "category" chosen in the first menu.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<select name="event">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select a Make</option>
    <option value="1">Honda</option>
    <option value="2">Volkswagen</option>
</select>

<select name="event2">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select a Model</option>
    <option value="1">Civic</option>
    <option value="2">Passat</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

There you go, an amazing submit button!

Comment: thanku so much. How do i connect this to my php program?

Comment: You should *really* take a look at this - http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: I am trying to create two dropdown menus in one of my forms so that they behave in the following way:

the first menu consists of "categories" of items, which I hard coded into the form. i am looking to relate the second menu with the first one such that, as soon as you choose an option from the first menu, the second menu lists only the name of those items that falls in the "category" chosen in the first menu.

Comment: If you're willing to do this dynamically look up some JavaScript tutorials, otherwise PHP can do this, but please mind that we're not here to write the code for you (http://stackoverflow.com/about refer to "Get answers to practical, detailed questions" part), we're here to help you with code you cannot figure out.